# Questions about length, offset, and padding in C++

Tags: c++, padding, sizeof

I'm a beginner who has just started learning C++. While studying data structures, I had a question about sizeof, and I would like to ask it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef char String[9];

// Definition of Student Record
struct StudentRecord
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int id;
    float gpa;
    int currentHours;
    int totalHours;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    StudentRecord student;
    StudentRecord students[100];

    // Size of memory allocation for student
    cout << "sizeof(student): " << sizeof(student) << endl;
    // Size of memory allocation for students
    cout << "sizeof(students): " << sizeof(students) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the following code:

`cout << "sizeof(student): " << sizeof(student) << endl;`

When I print sizeof(student), it returns 36. However, the sizes of student's member variables are clearly defined as 9, 9, 4, 4, 4, 4 from firstName to the end. Adding them up, I get 34. But the size of the student instance, which is an instance of StudentRecord, is 36.

I'm curious about how this 2-byte difference occurs. I found out from my Google search that it's related to padding. So, I understand that firstName and lastName both have sizes of 9, id and gpa have sizes of 4 each, adding up to 8, which is why an additional padding size of 1 is added to match the size of 9 for firstName and lastName. Similarly, currentHours and totalHours also have an additional padding size of 1, resulting in a total size of 36.

Is my understanding correct? Thank you!

I'd like to understand the process of padding that occurs on an actual computer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to satisfy the alignment requirements of all the basic types, a double or long should be aligned to 8 bytes, and an int/float should be aligned to 4 bytes, and a char should be aligned to 1 byte.

```
struct StudentRecord
{
    char names[18];
    // char padding[2]; // done by compiler.
    int id;
    float gpa;
    int currentHours;
    int totalHours;
};
```

in your object, your 2 strings have a total length of 9 + 9 = 18, it is followed by an `int`, this `int` must be aligned to 4 bytes, so the compiler inserts 2 bytes of padding after the 18 chars, therefore 18 + 2 = 20, and 20 % 4 = 0, now `id` is correctly aligned to 4 bytes.

Comment: I see that I was completely confused. I understand it perfectly now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Side note: You will confuse the heck out of other programmers with your `typedef char[9] String`.

Anyway:

- Each type has an alignment that is typically the same as its scalar size
- The first two members are arrays of `char` (alignment 1 byte). The second member ends at byte offset 18 within the object
- The third member is an `int`. On most platforms, that is 4 bytes with 4 byte alignment. 18 is not a multiple of 4. So we add 2 bytes of padding. The `id` will start at byte offset 20 from the start of the object
- All remaining members are also 4 byte with 4 byte alignment, so no further padding is required
- The internal size is then 9+9+2(padding)+4+4+4+4 = 36 byte
- The total size of the object needs to be a multiple of its alignment. The alignment of a class or struct is derived from the largest alignment of any of its members. That is 4 byte for the `int` and `float`. 36 is already a multiple of 4 so we don't need further padding at the back of the object

Comment: I see that I was completely confused. I understand it perfectly now. Thank you!!